# shimming the c open function on linux and logging its usage

Tags: c, linux

I'm currently trying to implement a c shim which sits between the open function from the c standard library and a program.

the shim should transparently write all file paths being opened to a log within a directory defined by the environment variable `IO_SHIM_PREFIX`

I have this working relatively well, but in order to achieve it I had to fake the fcntl.h header guards, and I think that there must be a better way.

If I include fcntl.h directly I get the following error

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o shim.so src/shim.c -ldl
src/shim.c:47:5: error: conflicting types for ‘open’
   47 | int open(const char *pathname, int flags){
      |     ^~~~
In file included from src/shim.c:16:
/usr/include/fcntl.h:168:12: note: previous declaration of ‘open’ was here
  168 | extern int open (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...) __nonnull ((1));
      |            ^~~~
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 1
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the `__nonnull ((1))` part at the end but I'm not much of a c programmer and I dont understand it.

### Makefile

```
CC=gcc
all: src/shim.c
    $(CC) -shared -fPIC -o shim.so src/shim.c -ldl
```

### src/shim.c

```c
// required for RTLD_NEXT
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

// this bypasses the header guard in bits/fcntl.h
// its a terrible idea, but I don't know the right way to do this.
#define _FCNTL_H
#include <bits/fcntl.h>
#undef _FCNTL_H

typedef int (*open_fn_ptr)(const char*, int);


void write_to_log(const char* prefix, const char* pathname, open_fn_ptr original_open){
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    pid_t tid = gettid();

    char* pattern;

    if (prefix[strlen(prefix) -1] == '/'){
        pattern = "%s%d_%d.log";
    }
    else{
        pattern = "%s/%d_%d.log";
    }
    
    
    int path_len = snprintf(NULL, 0, pattern, prefix, pid, tid);
    char* log_filepath = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * path_len);
    sprintf(log_filepath, pattern, prefix, pid, tid);


    int fd = original_open(log_filepath, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT);
    write(fd, pathname, strlen(pathname));
    write(fd, "\n", sizeof(char));      
    close(fd);

    free(log_filepath);
}

int open(const char *pathname, int flags){
        // acquire a pointer to the original implementation of open.
        open_fn_ptr original_open = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");

    const char* prefix = getenv("IO_SHIM_PREFIX");
    if (prefix != NULL) {
        write_to_log(prefix, pathname, original_open);
    }
        return original_open(pathname, flags);
}
```

### Usage example

```
IO_SHIM_PREFIX=`realpath .` LD_PRELOAD=./shim.so brave-browser
```

Comment: I think the error is saying that you should make your `open` also take a variable argument list.  Theoretically, you could just ignore it any extra args, but actually you should check if `flags` contain `O_CREAT` or `O_TMPFILE` and if so, read a `mode` argument from va_args and pass it on too.

Comment: ah! I didn't know c had variadic functions. thank you so much!

Comment: Any C function declaration ends with `, ...);` takes a variable length argument list. This question probably should have been asked on stack overflow.

Comment: If you just want to log calls, then perhaps `strace --trace=open` serves your needs?

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the suggestion, I'm aware of strace, I dismissed it in favor of a shim becuse of the performance impact it has on the watched process.

Comment: @pacmaninbw perhaps, but I wanted general code review on this as I'm not a experienced C programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     char* log_filepath = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * path_len);
> ```

`malloc()` returns a `void*`, which in C converts to any object-pointer type (unlike in C++, if you're used to that).  So the cast is unnecessary (it's slightly harmful, in that it distracts attention from more dangerous casts).  Also, because `char` is the unit of size, `sizeof (char)` can only be 1, so the multiplication is pointless.  That line should be simply

```
    char* log_filepath = malloc(path_len + 1);
```

Note the `+1` there - the code had a bug because we forgot to allocate space for the null character that ends the string.

There are other uses of `sizeof (char)` where plain old `1` would be more appropriate and easier to read.

---

Here, we assign a string literal to a `char*`:

> ```
>         pattern = "%s%d_%d.log";
> ```

That's poor practice, as writes to `*pattern` are undefined behaviour.  The best fix is to declare `pattern` to point to `const char`:

```
 const char *pattern;
```

I don't think it's necessary to choose between the two patterns - the filesystem interface will ignore consecutive directory separators, so it's safe to always use `"%s/%d_%d.log"`.

---

> ```
> // this bypasses the header guard in bits/fcntl.h
> // its a terrible idea, but I don't know the right way to do this.
> #define _FCNTL_H
> #include <bits/fcntl.h>
> #undef _FCNTL_H
> ```

Your intuition here is correct; we are relying on the compiler/platform innards here rather than the public interface. You should define `open_fn_ptr` to have the same signature as the library does:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, ...)
{
```

Then we can simply include the documented, supported POSIX header:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
```

---

> ```
>     // acquire a pointer to the original implementation of open.
>     open_fn_ptr original_open = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
> ```

That assignment is an invalid conversion in C - although `void*` can be assigned to any *object* pointer, that's not true for *function* pointers.  It might be worth drawing attention here using an explicit cast, though GCC will still emit a warning - see [Casting when using `dlsym()`](//stackoverflow.com/q/31526876/4850040).

Comment: that was incredibly helpful, thank you so much!